# TypeScript Intersection: Why is a function & string not never?

Tags: typescript

Kind of as it says on the tin.

```
type Foo = ((bar: boolean) => number) & string;
```

doesn't appear resolve to `never`, as `string & number` would. The type is still impossible, but why does it not show that as the case until one tries to assign to it?

Comment: You can *declare* such a type, but you'll never be able to assign anything with it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I understand that it's an impossible type, but why is it not `never`?

Comment: Intersections between primitives and non-primitives are allowed (despite often being impossible) in order to support "branding", a way to simulate nominal typing (see [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal)).  I don't know that this is particularly useful when the non-primitive is a function type, but my guess is that nobody cared to make it do anything different.  The reduction of impossible intersections to `never` has been slowly expanding over time to include more situations, but it's definitely not complete.

Comment: I can't find an explicit GitHub issue or official documentation that says *why* the intersection of functions with non-nullish primitives does not reduce to `never`, so I don't know if the above description of branded primitives would suffice as an authoritative answer.  What would you consider appropriate here if no such source is found?

Comment: Well, I suppose the 'branding' does provide *an* explanation... At least now I know it's likely intentional design and not a failure on the part of the interpreter, even if that design is... odd. Would you know of any way to get it to *not* do that?

Comment: To not... allow branding?  To not fail to reduce certain intersections to `never`?  Not sure what you're saying exactly.  (Or what the "interpreter" is... is it the TypeScript compiler?)  BTW please @-mention me "@jcalz" or I might not see your comment (I wasn't alerted to the previous one)

Comment: @jcalz By interpreter I meant both/either the typescript compiler and ts-server, which I'd assume are essentially the same.

And yes, that's precisely what I was after, although I'm realising in hindsight that request is essentially "Is there a way to remove core functionality out of TS" which I guess is a lot to ask.